# Am I the Goat Hero?

Tags: goscurry

At one point during my last journey through the world of Goscurry, the environment decided to give me this bizarre and frankly rather ominous message.

> GOAT
>
> HERO!

[image: GOAT HERO!]

Who, or what is this Goat Hero?  Is it me?

Comment: If you have to ask, you're not worthy of being the goat hero!  ;-)

Comment: The first rule of the Goat Hero is: you do not talk about the Goat Hero. The second rule of the Goat Hero is: the Goat Hero must not be confused with the Sheep Hero. And yes, the Goat Hero is within you!